# Re: Finding the live URL in Codenvy for python and django

Tags: python, django, codenvy

I am trying to create a web app using Codenvy using python and the Django framework, but I cannot seem to get anything running.

I have create the basic template of a webapp, and have pressed both the "run button" as well as the following in the terminal

```
cd /projects/hello && python manage.py runserver
```

Does anyone have any ideas or am I barking up the wrong tree here .

Many thanks,

Comment: Any feedback on this?